# Explicit Encryption with Spring Data Mongo fails when annotating custom class instead of simple type

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I try to implement explicit client side field level encryption with spring boot and mongodb.

I am using the following documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.encryption.explicit

Encryption and decryption works when I annotate simple types like String or Int like this:

```
@Document
data class AdressDocument(
    @ExplicitEncrypted(algorithm = EncryptionAlgorithms.AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_512_Random, keyAltName = "demo-data-key") private val zip: String,
    @ExplicitEncrypted(algorithm = EncryptionAlgorithms.AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_512_Random, keyAltName = "demo-data-key")  private val city: String)
```

I can save and read types with the standard mongo repositories, meaning data is encrypted and decrypted.

However, when I annotate the whole type (or a list of the type), the data is encrypted successfully (verified via mongodb compass), but reading fails with the following stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.bson.Document cannot be cast to class org.bson.BsonValue (org.bson.Document and org.bson.BsonValue are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.encryption.MongoEncryptionConverter.lambda$decrypt$1(MongoEncryptionConverter.java:102)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.encryption.MongoEncryptionConverter.decrypt(MongoEncryptionConverter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.encryption.EncryptingConverter.read(EncryptingConverter.java:32)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.encryption.MongoEncryptionConverter.read(MongoEncryptionConverter.java:65)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.encryption.MongoEncryptionConverter.read(MongoEncryptionConverter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1920)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$AssociationAwareMongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1983)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$AssociationAwareMongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1944)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PersistentEntityParameterValueProvider.getParameterValue(PersistentEntityParameterValueProvider.java:71)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.SpELExpressionParameterValueProvider.getParameterValue(SpELExpressionParameterValueProvider.java:49)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.KotlinClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator$DefaultingKotlinClassInstantiatorAdapter.extractInvocationArguments(KotlinClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:222)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.KotlinClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator$DefaultingKotlinClassInstantiatorAdapter.createInstance(KotlinClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:196)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:98)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:491)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readDocument(MappingMongoConverter.java:459)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:395)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:391)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:102)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$ReadDocumentCallback.doWith(MongoTemplate.java:3217)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:2851)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:2556)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:2537)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:865)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.findAll(SimpleMongoRepository.java:354)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.findAll(SimpleMongoRepository.java:136)
```

Mongo configuration classes:

```
@Configuration
class ClientEncryptionConfig(private val masterKeyProvider: MasterKeyProvider) {

    @Bean
    fun encryptionClient(): ClientEncryption {
        val clientEncryptionSettings = ClientEncryptionSettings.builder()
            .keyVaultMongoClientSettings(
                MongoClientSettings.builder()
                    .applyConnectionString(MongoConfig.connectionString)
                    .build()
            )
            .keyVaultNamespace(MongoConfig.keyVaultNamespace)
            .kmsProviders(masterKeyProvider.kmsProviders())
            .build()
        return ClientEncryptions.create(clientEncryptionSettings)
    }
}


@Configuration
class MongoConfig(private val clientEncryption: ClientEncryption, private val masterKeyProvider: MasterKeyProvider, private val appContext: ApplicationContext): AbstractMongoClientConfiguration(){

    companion object {
        val vaultCollectionName = "__keyVault"
        val dbName = "dbName"
        val keyVaultNamespace = "$dbName.$vaultCollectionName"
        val connectionString = ConnectionString("dummy-connection-string")
    }

    @Bean
    override fun mongoClient(): MongoClient {
        val autoEncryptionSettings = AutoEncryptionSettings.builder()
            .keyVaultNamespace(keyVaultNamespace)
            .kmsProviders(masterKeyProvider.kmsProviders())
            .bypassAutoEncryption(true)
            .build()

        return MongoClients.create(
            MongoClientSettings.builder()
                .applyConnectionString(connectionString)
                .autoEncryptionSettings(autoEncryptionSettings)
                .build()
        )
    }

    @Bean
    fun encryptingConverter(): MongoEncryptionConverter{
        val encryption = MongoClientEncryption.just(clientEncryption)
        val keyResolver = EncryptionKeyResolver.annotated{ _ -> EncryptionKey.keyAltName("demo-data-key")}
        return MongoEncryptionConverter(encryption, keyResolver)
    }

    override fun configureConverters(converterConfigurationAdapter: MongoCustomConversions.MongoConverterConfigurationAdapter) {
        converterConfigurationAdapter.registerPropertyValueConverterFactory(PropertyValueConverterFactory.beanFactoryAware(appContext))
    }

    override fun getDatabaseName(): String {
        return "databaseName"
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if some additional configuration is missing or if I just did something wrong.

I am using `Spring Boot 3.1.1` and `mongodb-crypt 1.8.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the issue on github, it is a bug which is currently beeing fixed:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/issues/4432

An intermediate solution is to skip the auto-encryption configuration when configuring the `MongoClient`.